# Error "RUN dotnet build "StockExchangeEmulator.sln" --no-restore"

Tags: docker, .net-core, .net-7.0

I got the error, when run the command

> docker build .

The error is

```
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/src/StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator/StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator.csproj]
```

My docker file is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["StockExchangeEmulator.sln", ""]
COPY ["Src/StockExchangeEmulator.Domain/StockExchangeEmulator.Domain.csproj", "src/StockExchangeEmulator.Domain/"]
COPY ["Src/StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator/StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator.csproj", "src/StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator/"]
COPY ["Tests/StockExchangeEmulator.Tests.csproj", "Tests/"]
COPY ["Directory.Packages.props", "."]
COPY ["Directory.Build.targets", "."]
COPY ["Directory.Build.props", "."]

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet build "StockExchangeEmulator.sln" --no-restore
```

My structure is:

```
-StockExchangeEmulator.sln
-Dockerfile
-Directory.Build.props
-Directory.Build.targets
-Directory.Packages.props
-Src
--StockExchangeEmulator.Domain
---StockExchangeEmulator.Domain.csproj
--StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator
---StockExchangeEmulator.Emulator.csproj
-Tests
---StockExchangeEmulator.Tests.csproj
```

My solution file alongside my dockerfile. Can you explain me the error?